# What value is correct to create a style for combining right-alignment and vertically-centered?

Tags: android

I created a `style` resource :

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <style name="ImpotsStyleLabel">
       <item name="android:background">@null</item>
       <item name="android:textColor">@color/txt_color</item>
       <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
       <item name="android:width">@dimen/labelWidth</item>
       <item name="android:gravity">right</item> // here is just right alignment
       <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">20dp</item>
       <item name="android:layout_marginRight">5dp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

In that file I want to add a `style` which will combine `right-alignment` and `center_vertical` gravity. How to do that ?

**--- EDIT ---**

Code of layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/ImpotsStyle"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        style="@style/ImpotsTitleStyle"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"> <!-- Title -->
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/title_tv"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/titre_parcelle"
            style="@style/ImpotsStyleTransparent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/marginLeftFieldset"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/marginRightFieldset"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margingBottomFieldset"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/paddingTopFieldset"
                android:background="@drawable/fieldset">
                <LinearLayout 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/identification"
                        style="@style/ImpotsStyleLabel"
                        />
                    <EditText 
                        android:id="@+id/identification"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:maxLength="25"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/marginRightScreen"
                        >
                        <requestFocus />
                    </EditText>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/marginLeftFieldset"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/marginRightFieldset"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margingBottomFieldset"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/paddingTopFieldset"
                android:background="@drawable/fieldset">
                <LinearLayout 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/commune"
                        style="@style/ImpotsStyleLabel"
                        />
                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/commune"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/marginRightScreen">
                    </Spinner>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you please share some code and to which `ViewGroup / View` do you want to add the style?

Comment: I want to apply the style to a TextView.

Comment: you asked how to align..i've showed you how to...start from a simple `LinearLayout` with only a spinner and a `TextView` and see that it's working..continue from there... good luck (-:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
    />

//style
<item name="android:gravity">right|center_vertical</item>
```

--- EDIT ----

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Text"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    style="@style/Alignment"
    android:background="#000000"
    />
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="0"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:entries="@array/i_am"
    />
</LinearLayout>

 <style name="Alignment">
    <item name="android:gravity">right|center_vertical</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: I don't really understand what is it you are trying to achieve. you want a gravity on a `TextView`? it means that the text is centered vertically in the textView dimensions and align to the right in the textView dimensions. are you trying to achieve something else?

Comment: I want the TextView's text to be right-aligned and centered vertically , and I want to place a Spinner after the TextView ! These two components are inside a horizontal LinearLayout ! You can try it and you will see the result :)

Comment: In your code : the gravity of the TextView is written inside the TextView ! I want the gravity to be inside a style resource because there will be many TextViews having the same characteristics !

Comment: I updated my question by adding the source code of the layout : what is wrong then in my code ?